# methods in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models, `Client` and `PaymentOptions`.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=False)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, unique=False)

class ClientPaymentOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=False, choices=CARD_TYPE)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=False, choices=CLIENT_PAYMENT_OPTION)
    percent = models.FloatField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=False)
    fixamount = models.FloatField(max_length=20, null=True, unique=False)
    itemcharged = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=False)
```

In my admin.py, I just want to have when I create a new `Client`, it will also create it's `ClientPaymentOption`.

I have this in my admin.py:

```
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #display list
    list_display = ('name','b_type','banner','logo',
                    'contact','address','account_type',
                    'status','currency','color','user',
                    )
    #display fields
    fields = ('name','b_type','banner','logo','contact',
              'address','account_type','status',
              'currency','color','user',
              )
    pass

admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

I have done this in my views.py,

```
client = Client.objects.create( .... )
ClientPaymentOption.objects.create( ...., client=client )
```

but i dont have any idea to do this in django admin.

do anyone have an idea about my situation? thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override standard django-admin change_view and add `ClientPaymentOption.objects.create( ...., client=client )`
there.
A short example from django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # A template for a very customized change view:
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/openstreetmap_change_form.html'

    def get_osm_info(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_osm_info()
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: What do get_osm_info(self) do? How i can pass value of elements from openstreetmap_change_form.html to model.py or admin.py